# Are homotopy equivalent path-connected spaces homotopy equivalent as pointed spaces?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $(X,x)$ and $(Y,y)$ be path-connected pointed topological spaces.

Is it true that the statement

''*$X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent*''

implies

''*$(X,x)$ and $(Y,y)$ are homotopy equivalent as pointed spaces*''? How can I prove this?

A *pointed homotopy equivalence* is a homotopy equivalence where the two involved homotopies are constant on the basepoints at every ''time''.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is false. Here is a standard exercise in algebraic topology. Define the following space $X$:
$$X = \{ (t x, t) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1], t \in [0, 1] \}$$
Clearly, $X$ is contractible; however, $(X, (0, 1))$ is not homotopy equivalent to the point as a pointed topological space!

Comment: Dear @Zhen Lin, thank you for the answer. Can there also be pointed CW-complexes $(X,x)$ and $(Y,y)$ with that property?

Comment: I do not know of an example off the top of my head. CW complexes are much nicer than general topological spaces, so it is more plausible that the claim is true in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Let me add to Zhen Lin's response an affirmative answer in the case of CW complexes. Namely, if $f:(X,x_0)\rightarrow(Y,y_0)$ is a homotopy equivalence (in the non-pointed sense) between CW complexes, where $x_0$, $y_0$ are 0-cells, then it is a homotopy equivalence rel basepoints. In fact, the same statement holds true for any pairs $(X, x_0)$ and $(Y,y_0)$ having the homotopy extension property.

This follows from, for example, Proposition 0.19 of Allen Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology," noting that CW pairs have the homotopy extension property and that the hypothesis that $A$ is a common subspace to $X$ and $Y$ in the proposition is no restriction on its application here.

Let me know if I am doing anything crazy.

Comment: in yout first paragraph you probably mean that then there exists a homotopy equivalence relative tomthe basepoints — f may well be move the basepoint, so your claim cannot work.

Comment: Perhaps I should have mentioned that $Y$ is path-connected as in the original question. Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be any homotopy equivalence. I can always homotope $f$ to some $\tilde f$ so that $\tilde f(x_0) = y_0$, since $(X,x_0)$ has the homotopy extension property. Now $\tilde f$ is a homotopy equivalence in the non-pointed sense, sending $x_0$ to $y_0$. If you replace $f$ by $\tilde f$ in my answer above, it should work.