# For $X$ and $Y$ path connected, if $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent, is there base point $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$ such that $(X,x) \simeq (Y,y)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

This question came up in my class.

For $X$ and $Y$ path connected, if $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent, are there base points $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$ such that $(X,x) $ is homotopy equivalent to $(Y,y)$?

It is indeed true that if $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent, then $\pi(X,x) \cong \pi(Y,y)$ for any choice of basepoint $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$. But is it true that we can find basepoints so that $(X,x) \simeq (Y,y)$?

Note that if $X$ is not path connected, we can pick a space that is contractible but not pointed-contractible to any of its point.

More generally, is it true that if we have a homotopy $f,g \colon X \rightarrow Y$, can we find a based homotopy $f,g \colon (X,x) \rightarrow (Y,y)$?

Thanks!

EDIT: found a question that answers this question: [Are homotopy equivalent path-connected spaces homotopy equivalent as pointed spaces?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369401/are-homotopy-equivalent-path-connected-spaces-homotopy-equivalent-as-pointed-spa?rq=1)

Comment: Re your fourth sentence: take a space $X$ which is contractible but not pointed-contractible to any point and let $Y=\ast$.

Comment: To supplement the comment of @Tyrone, take a look at Hatcher, p. 18 for some examples.